# AngularFire 0.5 $remove. Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

new to angular here and I have a ng-repeat list with ng-click="remove(item)" button that triggers a remove function:

```
$scope.remove = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        $scope.items.$remove(item);
};
```

While $scope.items.$remove(); works well at removing all items in the model. I'm not exactly sure why it's throwing me an error if I pass an item for removal. Below is the error I'm getting.

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Ga (https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js:12:230)
    at H.J.F (https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js:134:213)
    at Object.object.$remove (https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.js:160:26)
    at Scope.MyCtrl.$scope.removeShape (http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:24:23)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9977:21
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17678:17
    at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11668:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11768:23)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30) angular.js:9193
(anonymous function) angular.js:9193
(anonymous function) angular.js:6746
Scope.$apply angular.js:11770
$delegate.__proto__.$apply VM21684:855
(anonymous function) angular.js:17677
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle
```

Appreciate in advance for helping me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$remove` takes a string as an argument, the key name of the child to remove, not the object itself. Iterate over *both* the key and value in ng-repeat so you'll have access to the key. For example:

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">
  <a ng-click="remove(key)">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "build" in `$index` key that you can use in angular ng-repeat, and pass that $index to your remove method:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</a>
</div>
```